# In NEAT, how do node numbers work?

Tags: neural-networks, reinforcement-learning, genetic-algorithms, neat, neuroevolution

I have read a lot of debates about node ids and such. I'm not 100% sure how it works, but I am assuming the next node added to a network would be the next number in that specific networks list?

For example, say we start with a network with 2 inputs 1 output (nodes 1,2,3). Let's say in generation 1, one network splits a connection creating node 4. Then in generation 2, a different network splits a different connection. This would be node 4 for that specific network right? From my understanding (correct me if I'm wrong), this second split would result in 1 new innovation connection. The connection from the input to node 4 would be new but the connection from node 4 to 3 would already exist from the first split?